# SVG files from Wordpress upload ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: wordpress, nginx, svg, pagespeed

I installed Nginx with Pagespeed modules and Wordpress.
I uploaded SVG file into Wordpress and try to view it in Chrome.
The error is something like this.
[image: Google Chrome shows errors]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share the code that makes up one of these `ic-shop*.svg` icons?

Comment: Are the svg files delivered as mime type image/svg+xml?